# Automated Releas enote creation for Azure devops releases

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

We are looking for an automated way to create Release note for each of our prod releases from Azure devops server release pipelines (in yaml) to update the release note  details to both a central wiki and the application code hosting repo.